# Update one table from using specific data from multiple columns of another table

Tags: postgresql-9.6

Working with two tables, **c** and **t**. In table **c** is an ID from table **t**. Using some criteria in **t**, I want to change the referenced t.id in **c** from one row in **t** to another:

Table **c** now:

```
|  id | tid |
|   1 | 100 |
|   2 | 103 |
|   3 | 104 |
```

Table **t** has pairs of rows with the same "name" but different "mod". The "mod" field is null except where I want to make the swap.

Table **t**

```
|  id | name |  mod |
| 100 |  car | base |
| 101 |  car |      |
| 102 |  bus |      |
| 103 |  bus | base |
| 104 | bike | base |
| 105 | bike |      |
```

I want to change the current c.tid from the t.id with t.mod = base to t.id of same name but t.mod = null. So the resulting table **c** would be:

```
|  id | tid |
|   1 | 101 |
|   2 | 102 |
|   3 | 105 |
```

Basically swapping the reference from the "base" rows to the null rows. I've tried to update using subqueries but obviously getting the "more than one row returned..." error.

The tables aren't large so performance is not an issue. I'm thinking maybe a temp table containing both id's from t (matching name, one id from "base", one id from null) and then a simple update from one to the other.

I wouldn't mind a more elegant solution, like using the name column as a key field somehow?

EDIT: A temp table solution worked fine. I'd still like something more elegant, but I guess "just works" is OK.

```
SET search_path = "database";
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp (baseid, newid) ON COMMIT DROP AS SELECT * FROM
 (SELECT t1.id, t2.id FROM actype t1 
 JOIN actype t2 ON (t1.name = t2.name)
 WHERE t1.specifier = 'BASE' and t1.id != t2.id
)AS foo;
UPDATE c SET tid = newid FROM temp WHERE tid = temp.baseid;
```

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977). Are you really still running Postgres 9.6? If so, why?

Comment: Yes, I'm still running Postgres 9.6? Why? Because I'm not in control of the environment. Why do you feel the need to comment on that?  Thanks for the link to the newbie page, but I'm fine completing this task with a temp table. I was just hoping to gather a fresh perspective on a solution I might not be aware of.